# Helping with comparison statement

Tags: shell, if-statement

I am trying to check the OS X version of a workstation and if it's 10.7 or higher do this. On the other hand, if it's before 10.7 do something else. Can you guys point me in the right direction as to why I am getting the error message below?

Thank you very much!

```
#!/bin/sh

cutOffOS=10.7
osString=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
echo $osString
current=${osString:0:4}
echo $current
currentOS=$current
echo $currentOS
if [ $currentOS >= cutOffOS ] ; then
    echo "10.8 or later"
    chflags nohidden ~/Library
else
    echo "oh well"
fi
```

Output when run the above script:

10.8.4

10.8

10.8

/Users/Tuan/Desktop/IDFMac.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 11: [: 10.8: unary operator expected

oh well

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the (very real) issue that `sw_vers` can return a version "number" with 3 parts (e.g. 10.7.5), `bash` cannot deal with floating point numbers, only integers. You need to break the version number into its integer components, and test them separately.

```
cutoff_major=10
cutoff_minor=7
cutoff_bug=0

osString=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
os_major=${osString%.*}
tmp=${osString#*.}
os_minor=${tmp%.*}
os_bug=${tmp#*.}

# Make sure each is set to something other than an empty string
: ${os_major:=0}
: ${os_minor:=0}
: ${os_bug:=0}

if [ "$cutoff_major" -ge "$os_major" ] &&
   [ "$cutoff_minor" -ge "$os_minor" ] &&
   [ "$cutoff_bug" -ge "$os_bug" ]; then
    echo "$cutoff_major.$cutoff_minor.$cutoff_bug or later"
    chflags nohidden ~/Library
else
    echo "oh well"
fi
```

Comment: Good one! Just for curiosity: what about if one version is 3 numbers format and the other just 2?

Comment: Good point; I forgot to account for that. In `bash`, you can use undefined variables in `(( x > y ))` and they'll be treated as 0. For POSIX shell, you'll have to set empty variables to 0 explicitly. I'll update.